# Passing Down React Native State from ListView

Tags: javascript, mobile, reactjs, react-native

I'm having trouble passing down state from my a React Native ListView.

I'm currently trying to extend the functionality of the tutorial found here.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html#content

I want to add the ability to press any movie and get more information about it.

Here is the ListView being rendered

```
    renderMovie(movie) {
        this.movie = movie;
        return (
          <View
          style={styles.container}
          >
            <Image
              source={{uri: movie.posters.thumbnail}}
              style={styles.thumbnail}
            />
            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.rightContainer} onPress={this._onPressMovie.bind(this)}>
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{movie.title}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.year}>{movie.year}</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        );
      }
```

When the `onPress` happens this fires

```
    _onPressMovie(){
        this.setState({ showMovieInfo: !this.state.showMovieInfo, movie: this.movie});
    }
```

When `this.state.showMovieInfo` is true, an earlier if statement gets called

```
    render() {

        if(!this.state.loaded) {
          return this.renderLoadingView();
        }

        if(this.state.showMovieInfo) {
          return this.renderMovieInfo()
        }

        return (
          <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderMovie.bind(this)}
            style={styles.listView}/>
        );
      };
```

Instead of passing down the movie info that was pressed it passes down the last movie that was rendered down to here.

```
    renderMovieInfo() {
        return (
          <TouchableHighlight style={styles.container} onPress={this._onPressMovieInfo.bind(this)}>
            <View>
              <MovieInfo {...this.state}/>
            </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>
          );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working! in the onPress I needed to call it like this.

```
onPress ={() => this.onPressMovie(movie)}
```

and take away this

```
this.movie = movie;
```